# Finding of amount of elements by using special cycle with condition

Tags: r, sum, cycle

I have simple dataset with digital values. For example, `x<-c(3,4,6,7,8,4,5,3,4,3,5,6)`. I need to count number of elements by this way: i need to find minimal amount of elements which please condition: first element/sum of all elements should be greater than 0,95 or first element plus second element/sum of all elements should be greater than 0,95 and so on. For example, 3/58<0,95; 3+4/58<0,95; 3+4+6/58<0,95 and so on. I should stop when it will be greater than 0,95 and count number of elements that i used frm dataset. How can i do this?

Comment: Based on the example, sum is less than 95

Comment: @akrun maybe i gave bad example, i say it overall, i need any ideas how to do that

Comment: I would use `n <- 1;head(x[cumsum(x)>95], n)` if you are looking to subset the vector

Comment: @akrun I editted my question to make clearer explanation

Comment: You may need `sum(cumsum(x) < 95)`

Comment: @akrun thit is not helpful for me

Comment: ok, that is based on your description.  Then, your description may not be that helpful

Comment: ok, can you then explain how this peace of works?

Comment: You only said that it is not the correct one.  The codes logic is that `cumsum(x)` gives cumulative sum of the vector, then `< 95`, creates a logical vector from the output.  `sum` of the logical gives the count because TRUE/FALSE -> 1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min(which(cumsum(x)/sum(x) > 0.95))
#[1] 12
```

This gives which element in `x` first has a cumulative sum up to that point that exceeds 95% of the total of `x`.

In this case, the total of `x` is 58, and 95% of that is 55.1. At the 11th element of `x`, the cumulative total is only 58-6 = 52, so you need all 12 elements to total more than 55.1.

Comment: One more question, if I want to show elements that matches such condition, how can i do this?

Comment: Cause there is a problem, if i do such cumsum(x)/sum(x) < 0.95, 1 element will be not included

Comment: Perhaps it'd help to look at `data.frame(x,  cuml = cumsum(x),  cuml_share = cumsum(x)/sum(x),  exceeds = cumsum(x)/sum(x) > 0.95)` to see what's going on.